# Google Script - Create copy and rename workbook

Tags: javascript

Wondering if anyone could help?

I've got a master spreadsheet which is protected so users can only edit certain cells, what I'm trying to do is create a copy of the workbook and rename it when a user submits a form.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. Pls read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're in the script editor on the master spreadsheet which the form is linked to, this snippet from the [Google Apps Script Docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#copy(String)) should help. Put it in a function and then add a form submit trigger for that function.

```
function onFormSubmit() {
    // This code makes a copy of the current spreadsheet and names it 
    // appropriately
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    ss.copy("Copy of " + ss.getName());
}
```

To add a trigger go to Edit > Current Projects Triggers > Add > choose function > (Events) From Spreadsheet > On Form Submit.

Comment: If you feel that my answer helped you, you could [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).